# How may I check ECS container agent configuration in ECS Fargate Task?

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

For EC2 launch type I'm able to check agent configuration in `/etc/ecs/ecs.config` file at EC2 container instance. But is it possible to find out the same info at ECS Fargate Task? For example, I'd like to know, what is the timeout between SIGTERM and SIGKILL (`ECS_CONTAINER_STOP_TIMEOUT`). I wonder should it be possible to retrieve such info from [Amazon ECS Task Metadata Endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-metadata-endpoint.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Fargate, timeout between `SIGTERM` and `SIGKILL` is the same as the default setting of 30 seconds.

Comment: Is it possible to configure timeout parameter at Fargate?

Comment: No, it is not currently possible to configure the timeout parameter.

Comment: Is there any workaround @SamuelKarp? having a service that runs a queue worker that has to exit gracefully and might take more than 30 seconds.

Comment: I'm seeing the same limitation for scale-in of my Sidekiq workers (I want to have the scale-in process wait for the worker to complete its jobs). So far the only workaround I've found is to not use a Service, use a Task directly, and code up my own scale-out/in process with https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_RunTask.html

Answer (score 0):

For newer Fargate platform versions, you can use the `stopTimeout` [container definition parameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#container_definition_timeout). Note the maximum value of 120 seconds:

> For tasks that use the Fargate launch type, the task or service requires platform version 1.3.0 or later (Linux) or 1.0.0 or later (for Windows). The max stop timeout value is 120 seconds. However, if the parameter isn't specified, the default value of 30 seconds is used.